# Spline type to achieve a specific result

Tags: splines

Is there a type of spline which can produce (approximately) the following result given the specified points indicated. I want to be able to specify how curved the corners are from the "centre points" so that I get "very square" corners to "very round" corners. Sorry about my shakey hand ! Points along a line should produce (roughly) a linear curve.

I found quite a few questions and answers online about this but they all seem to be B-spline related, and don't (I think) quite capture my constraints. If anybody knows what I'm looking for, direction to an online reference/article would be great.

My points always appear on an integer lattice (grid), and are always equally spaced.

I'm looking for something low complexity, but which I can pass a value, say `t` in `[0,1]` and returns the `(x,y)` position of the curve at that time. I realise I could probably build a function like this piece-wise, but wondered if there is a ready made spline solution (piece-wise equation) which could achieve the same result.

Maybe B-splines or NURBS are the answer, but maybe they are heavy on computation too...

[image]

---

Given Sirisian's answer below, I suddenly realised how Bezier curves work. Wow they really are a clever idea!
[image]

Everything seems centred around a single `t` value, e.g.

```
l1(t) = a+t(b-a)
l2(t) = b+t(c-b))
m(t)  = l1(t)+t(l2(t)-l1(t))
```

We can expand `m` to simplify if necessary.

---

I think B-Splines give a nice result, e.g. see below. It also has the advantage of not being restricted to a uniform grid. Not sure about speed of computation yet though...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple quadratic Bézier curve would be sufficient.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves

Implementation-wise you'd just draw a line for horizontally or vertically connected nodes and then a curve for the other cases.

An alternative that would be more complex would be use to use an arc like in the SVG spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands

There are implementation details in the spec for how it functions.